# How do I find siblings with xml.dom.minidom?

Tags: python, xml

I have a block SKOS files that I am trying to read with xml.dom.minidom. Here's a sample entry:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://...">
     <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept"/>
     <skos:narrowMatch rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Biology"/>
     <skos:narrowMatch rdf:resource="http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.01540"/>
     <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Biology and Biochemistry</skos:prefLabel>
     <skos:scopeNote xml:lang="en">Used for all coverage of biology and biochemistry unless a more narrow term applies.</skos:scopeNote>
</rdf:Description>
```

I can access all the skos:prefLabel's with something like ...

```
for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('skos:prefLabel'):
    print element.firstChild.data
```

but I want the associated skos:ScopeNote, too. Am I just using the wrong tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this

```
discriptions = doc.getElementsByTagName("rdf:Description")
for dis in discriptions:
    siblings = dis.childNodes
    for sib in siblings:
        if str(sib.nodeName)=="skos:prefLabel" :
            preflabel = sib.firstChild.data
        if str(sib.nodeName)=="skos:scopeNote":
            scopenote = sib.firstChild.data
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a better way, but I would do the following:

1. Get the parent node
2. From the parent, search for 'skos:scopeNote'

Here is the code:

```
for element in doc.getElementsByTagName('skos:prefLabel'):
    print element.firstChild.data
    sibbling = element.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('skos:scopeNote')[0]
    print sibbling.firstChild.data
```

## Discussion

- Since `getElementsByTagName()` returns a list, and I am sure that there is one node of that name under the parent, I went ahead and grab the first node (index `[0]`)
- I tried `element.nextSibbling`, but it returns the new line as a "node". I can keep querying the next sibbling until I find what I am looking for, but that is a lot of code. Also, there is no guarantee that *scopeNote* will follow *prefLabel*, so it is safer to go up to the parent and search.